# Make my flip on hover query script script work on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

I am currently working on my website and am using the following code to flip a card on hover. However, I tested it on mobile and the card flips on touch but doesn't flip back on click out, only if i click another card. Does anyone know how or if I can adapt this code (or have a different code I could use?) to make this work on mobile. Thank you!

`$('.card').hover(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('flipped');
});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hover()` accepts a second (optional) parameter that gets run when you hover out

```
$('.card').hover(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('flipped');
  },
  function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('flipped');
});
```

But on mobile devices `hover()` isn't a actual jquery mobile event it uses `touch` events internally so if it didn't work you might need to use `touchstart` and `touchend` events and bind on them

EDIT : `touchstart` is similar to click and `touchend` is similar to mouseup event on mobile .If you include jquery mobile you can do this

*Snip 1*

```
$(".card").on('touchstart',function() {
     $(this).toggleClass('flipped');
});
```

This would be like a "toggle button" when you touch and release it would keep its state untill you do it again.Whereas this

*Snip 2*

```
$(".card").on('touchstart',function() {
     $(this).toggleClass('flipped');
});

$(".card").on('touchend',function() {
     $(this).toggleClass('flipped');
});
```

would behave like a "turbo button" the moment you release your touch it would revert back to its original state

Comment: Ok sorry, I just saw the rest of your post. I barely scraped together that piece of jquery code I posted so I don't know what you mean by bind. Would that be easy to add in?

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for this help. Really appreciate you taking the time :)

Comment: @Alyssa Jaisle Cheers! It was nothing just pls mark the answer (left side "right" symbol) if it worked as desired :)